# Java (BigInteger from byte array)

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm using following code to create a `BigInteger` from hexadecimal string and print in to output.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Number in hexadecimal form
        String HexString = "e04fd020ea3a6910a2d808002b30309d";
        // Convertation from string to byte array
        byte[] ByteArray = toByteArray(HexString);
        // Creation of BigInteger from byte array
        BigInteger BigNumber = new BigInteger(ByteArray);
        // Print result
        System.out.print(BigNumber + "\n");
    }
    public static String toHexString(byte[] array) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(array);
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }
}
```

After execution of this code I'm get a following result:

`-42120883064304190395265794005525319523`

But I'm expected to see this result:

`298161483856634273068108813426242891933`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're passing in a byte array where the first byte has a top bit that is set - making it negative. From the [constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-byte:A-):

> Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

A two's-complement binary representation with a leading set bit is negative.

To get the result you want, you can do any of:

- Prefix the hex string with `"00"` so that you'll always get a top byte of 0
- Pass the hex string straight into the `BigInteger(String, int)` constructor, where the sign is inferred from the presence or absence of `"-"` at the start of the string. (Obviously you'd pass in 16 as the base.)
- Use the `BigInteger(int, byte[])` constructor, passing 1 as the `signum` value

If your *real* context is that you've already got the byte array, and you were only parsing it from a hex string for test purposes, I'd use the third option. If you've genuinely got a hex string as input, I'd use the second option.

Comment: Thank you! Following your answer I fixed this problem.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(HexString, 16);
```

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know the existence of this constructor. Well done!

Comment: Thank you! I'm like your answer and will use it in future.

Comment: Why did someone downvote the correct answer? You really shouldn't do that.

Comment: I don't know why it was downgradred, but text of the question was stating; " create a BigInteger from hexadecimal string" ... it didn't not say it had to pass thought byte[]... if it was for the missing explanation, I really don't know how to explain that the method exist in the class :(